# Union of two objects with Python

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I have two objects (A and B) and I need to get the union of them. A has a face area of 200 units and B has 10 units. In addition, B falls completely inside A. If I use join (Ctrl+J) then the face area becomes 210 units (200+1). However, if I do "Union" using Bool Tool then I get an area of 200 units (what I am looking for as B falls inside A).

There will be thousands of objects to merge between them, thus, I am looking for a way to do the union operation using python. Is there any way of doing that? Can I use the Bool Tool with python? Or, import some function then do the operation.

Comment: Any API built in tool a Blender User invokes , can be used in a Python Script. So if you look in the Info Window you can see the history of User Actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

---

The Info Window shows Python statements for user actions.  You can find the command invoked for Bool Tool there.

For example

`bpy.ops.object.booltool_auto_difference()`

was found after a Bool Tool Difference operation.

You may copy and  paste from the Info Window.

Comment: I am quite new in Blender and did not notice that feature. It's super helpful and I figured out that I can use     bpy.ops.object.booltool_auto_union()    to accomplish my objective. Thanks a lot

Comment: I may not be new to Blender.  I am inconsistent with the use of Blender... .. Everyday I randomly use Blender .. I realize .. I have partially forgotten features and I partially learn features ‍➕➖✖➗❕‍